# Pentadactyl: command to search BTDIGG.org

Tags: javascript, firefox, vimperator

I'd like to add a [pentadactyl](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/) (it's a fork of vimperator) command to search [btdigg](http://btdigg.org/) torrent search engine. The query structure is shown in the example below - where "test with space" is searched:

```
http://btdigg.org/search?q=test+with+space
```

I tried to execute:

```
:command -nargs=* btdigg open http://btdigg.org/search?q= <args>
```

It brings me to the title page what ever I give it. So it doesn't work. Can You fix it? I want to the following command

```
:btdigg arg1 arg2 arg3
```

to search "arg1 arg2 arg3" string in www.btdigg.org

**Edit**:

So here's my best try. It's a javascript code to search a given site(s). If I could make it work - the problem with btdigg will also be solved:

```
javascript <<EOF
    dactyl.searchWikis = function (selection) {
        let parsedSelection = selection.replace(/^\s*/, "" ).replace(/\s*$/, "" ).replace(/\s+/g, "+" );
        dactyl.execute( ":tabopen http://www.scholarpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=" + selection);
        dactyl.execute( ":tabopen http://en.citizendium.org/wiki?title=Special:Search&search=" + selection);
    };
EOF

:command  bookSearch -nargs=* -js dactyl.searchWikis(<args>)
```

But PentaDactyl doesn't see it. Can You please make Pentadactyl see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the [add-to-search-bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-to-search-bar/) addon, then right-click on the btdigg's search bar and choose "Add to search bar". Say You'll name it `btdigg`, After that:

```
:btdigg arg1 arg2 arg3
```

would search "arg1 arg2 arg3" in btdigg.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an external site: http://yubnub.org/. It even has the related command ready: http://yubnub.org/kernel/man?args=btdigg. Basically you install the YubNub search plugin from http://mycroftproject.com/search-engines.html?name=yubnub (pick up the Mirror) and set the default search engine in your ~/.pentadactylrc to match it.